# SQL Pulling the latest information and information from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a record table that is recording changes within a table. I can pull the data from the first table fine, however when i try to join in another table to add some of its column information it stops displaying the information.

```
PartNumber | PartDesc | value | date
1          | test     | 1     | 3/4/2015
```

I wanted to include the Aisle tag's from the location table

```
PartNumber| AisleTag    | AisleTagTwo
1         | A1          | N/A
```

here is what i have as my sql statement so far

```
Select t1.PartNumber, t1.PartDesc , t1.NewValue ,  t1.Date,t2.AisleTag,t2.AisleTagTwo
from InvRecord t1
JOIN PartAisleListTbl t2 ON t1.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
where Date = (select max(Date) from InvRecord where t1.PartNumber = InvRecord.PartNumber)
order by t1.PartNumber
```

it is coming up blank, my original sql statement doesn't include anything from t2. I am not sure what approach to go with in terms of getting the data combined any help is much appreciated thank you !

this should be the end result

```
PartNumber | PartDesc | value | date     | AisleTag    | AisleTagTwo
1          | test     | 1     | 3/4/2015 | A1          | N/A
```

Comment: The only thing I see about your query is that you don't alias InvRecord in your subquery.  It might confuse SQL because you're referencing the same table twice.   Try aliasing in both places.

Comment: are you sure partaislelisttbl has the part number in question?

Comment: the table is so far empty yes, but i added a few items that are listed on table 1 , and added it to table 2 along with some dummy data . while not every item listed in table 1 is not listed in table 2 some of it is, i was expecting to at least see the some part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the most recent row (based on Date) for each PartNumber in Table A and append data from Table B (joined on PartNumber):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.PartNumber
         , A.PartDesc
         , A.NewValue
         , A.Date
         , B.AisleTag
         , B.AisleTagTwo
         , DateSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.PartNumber ORDER BY A.Date DESC)
    FROM InvRecord A
    LEFT JOIN PartAisleListTbl B
        ON A.PartNumber = B.PartNumber
) A
WHERE A.DateSeq = 1
ORDER BY A.PartNumber
```

Comment: Well when i use this the information comes up but the PartAisleListTbl  isn't showing up it is coming up null even with the information I know is in that table. It just comes up as all null.

Comment: This is a LEFT JOIN so it has the potential to return NULLs whenever the PartNumber cannot be found in B. If this is not the desired result then you can change it to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: well yes this is the desired results, if it is null or not in there i want it to be null. the problem i am seeing is i have some parts listed in table B, but when i go to that part number it is still showing up as null for some reason.

Comment: Wait Now I am seeing the data. Yes this is the right answer I am looking for ty :)

Comment: Then you have a problem in your dataset. The only condition in this query that would affect your dataset in such a manner is `ON A.PartNumber = B.PartNumber`. A couple ideas: is the data actually committed? Are you absolutely certain your keys match in type and value?

Comment: I am looking at the data and it was my mistake, I never committed the data, and the B table only has 4 entry's to it. I will be more diligent with the data. I tried it before but i should of checked if the data was committed right.

Comment: No problem. It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your's isn't working... is date in both t1 and t2 by any chance?

Here's it re factored to use a inline view instead of a correlated query  wonder if it makes a difference.

```
Select t1.PartNumber, t1.PartDesc , t1.NewValue ,  t1.Date,t2.AisleTag,t2.AisleTagTwo
from InvRecord t1
JOIN PartAisleListTbl t2 
  ON t1.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
JOIN (select max(Date) mdate, PartNumber from InvRecord GROUP BY PartNumber) t3
  on t3.partNumber= T1.PartNumber
 and T3.mdate = T1.Date 
order by t1.PartNumber
```

Comment: date is not on the second table.

Comment: By second table you do mean PartAisleListTbl t2 because as stated that one doesn't have a date column.  also when i try your statement i am getting an error saying t3 and T3.mdate

Answer (score 1):

Are you returning no records at all, or only records with `AisleTag` and `AisleTagTwo` as null?

Your sentence "it is coming up blank, my original sql statement doesn't include anything from t2." makes it sound like you're getting records with nulls for the `t2` fields.

If you are, then you probably have a record in `t2` that has nulls for those fields.

For troubleshooting purposes, try running the query without the `WHERE` clause:

```
Select t1.PartNumber, t1.PartDesc , t1.NewValue , t1.Date,t2.AisleTag,t2.AisleTagTwo
from InvRecord t1
JOIN PartAisleListTbl t2 ON t1.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
order by t1.PartNumber
```

If you do get records, your problem is with the `WHERE` clause.  If you don't, your problem is with the `PartNumber` fields in `InvRecord` and `PartAisleListTbl` not matching.

Comment: Well when i use the left join instead of join the column information comes up but the PartAisleListTbl  isn't showing up. Your right that table is mostly empty, I was hoping to list at least what data is on there based on the part number that is listed there but it isn't.

Comment: Update: yes your right the data is not macthing my mistake